# How do i display friends of a user in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I am creating a friend list module.
I have 2 tables: users table and friends table. I want the program to display the friends of a user without displaying the user as one of his/her own friend.

My table looks like

Users table

```
---------- ---------- ---------
user_id   | username | password
-------------------------------
1         | elexis | *******
-------------------------------
2         | rooney | *******
-------------------------------
3         | wayne | *******
-------------------------------
4         | June   | *******
-------------------------------
```

Friends table

```
---------- ----------
user_id   | friend_id
---------------------
1         | 3
-----------
2         | 1
-----------
2         | 4
-----------
1         | 2
```

Expected output of user_id 1 (who is elexis) should be

```
User_id  friend_id    Username
1           3           Wayne
2           1           Rooney
```

My code is thus:

```
SELECT t1.user_id,t1.friend_id, t2.username 
FROM friends AS t1 
LEFT JOIN users AS t2 
ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id) 
OR (t1.friend_id = t2.user_id)  
WHERE t1.user_id = 1
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
User_id    Friend_id    Username
1              5.       Elexis
1              1        Elexis
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `Users` to a query that contains distinct pairs of user with id = 1 and each pair:

```
SELECT f.*, u.username
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, friend_id FROM Friends WHERE user_id = 1
  UNION
  SELECT friend_id, user_id FROM Friends WHERE friend_id = 1
) f ON f.friend_id = u.user_id;
```

Or, if you want to pass the user parameter only once:

```
SELECT f.*, u.username
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, friend_id FROM Friends 
  UNION
  SELECT friend_id, user_id FROM Friends
) f ON f.friend_id = u.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a4f1aeba1bd3bad35df2c140126f428).

Answer (score 0):

You can union two qieroes which give you the result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE friend
>     (`user_id` int, `friend_id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO friend
>     (`user_id`, `friend_id`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 3),
>     (2, 1),
>     (2, 4),
>     (1, 2)
> ;
>
>
> CREATE TABLE users
>     (`user_id` int, `username` varchar(6), `password` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO users
>     (`user_id`, `username`, `password`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'elexis', '*******'),
>     (2, 'rooney', '*******'),
>     (3, 'wayne', '*******'),
>     (4, 'June', '*******')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT f.*, u. username FROM friend f JOIN users u ON f.friend_id = u.user_id WHERE f.user_id = 1 AND f.`friend_id` NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM friend WHERE friend_id = 1)
> UNION 
> SELECT f.*, u.username FROM friend f JOIN users u ON f.user_id = u.user_id WHERE friend_id = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | friend_id | username
> ------: | --------: | :-------
>       1 |         3 | wayne   
>       2 |         1 | rooney
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d2ac1e2919117eb36b25bf46b99865e)*

Comment: How I'm I supposed to get the username of the friend?

Comment: do you mead user ´ name? you have to join a second user table

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on Friend_id and select user_id from Friends table.

```
SELECT f.user_id,f.friend_id,u.username
FROM friends f JOIN users u
ON f.user_id=f.friend_id
```

This gives you output:

```
user_id | friend_id | username
      1 |         3 | Wayne
      2 |         1 | Elexis
```

Comment: Instead of 'Elexis' the result should be 'rooney'.

Comment: I'm getting blank record. It's fetching no data